# Object reference not set to an instance of an object using Radio-button

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button

I get this error and I think it comes from a radio button. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Here is the aspx:

```
  <asp:RadioButton ID="radL" runat="server" GroupName="Gender" Checked="false" Text="L" AutoPostBack="true" />
   <asp:RadioButton ID="radP" runat="server" GroupName="Gender" Checked="false" Text="P" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

The code behind:

```
   RadioButton radL = (RadioButton)editedItem.FindControl("radL");
   RadioButton radP = (RadioButton)editedItem.FindControl("radP");
   RadioButton JAN = (RadioButton)editedItem.FindControl("JAN");

   if (radL.Checked == true)
   {
       JAN = radL;
   }
   else
   {
       JAN = radP;
   }
   SqlConnection conn1 = BusinessTier.getConnection();
   conn1.Open();
   int flg = BusinessTier.SavePersonalInfo(conn1, 1, txtEmpNo.Text.ToString().Trim(), txtJobTitle.Text.ToString().Trim(), Convert.ToInt32(txtKod.Text.ToString().Trim()), txtJenis.Text.ToString().Trim(),
   txtNama.Text.ToString().Trim(), txtNokp.Text.ToString().Trim(), TLAHIR.SelectedDate.Value, Convert.ToInt32(txtUmur.Text.ToString().Trim()), JAN.Text.ToString().Trim(), txtRas.Text.ToString().Trim(), txtBadge.Text.ToString().Trim(), txtKerja.Text.ToString().Trim(),
   txtKodclin.Text.ToString().Trim(), txtKc.Text.ToString().Trim(), txtAdd1.Text.ToString().Trim(), txtAdd2.Text.ToString().Trim(), txtAdd3.Text.ToString().Trim(), txtAlgr.Text.ToString().Trim(), Session["sesUserID"].ToString(), "N");
   BusinessTier.DisposeConnection(conn1);
```

Comment: If you are getting this as an exception, can you please post the stack trace. It will help isolate the lines of code causing the issue.

Comment: Why can't you debug and find out what line it is actually blowing up on?

Comment: do you have a RadioButton with the Id of "JAN"?

Comment: if i check the codes line by line,all the items hold the value and the JAN radio button hold the value of either radL or radP radio button checked.

Comment: You don't have any radiobutton `JAN` in your designer part. That's why you are getting this error. Let it be only `RadioButton JAN;`. Then assign value to it.

Comment: or simply, you can take it as a string and assign the selected radiobutton's text to it. There's no need to initialize it as `RadioButton`

Answer (score 0):

you should check for null before casting result of a FindControl() statement

for e.g this line

```
RadioButton JAN = (RadioButton)editedItem.FindControl("JAN");
```

should be changed to

```
RadioButton JAN;
if(editedItem.FindControl("JAN") != null)
{
   RadioButton JAN = (RadioButton)editedItem.FindControl("JAN");
}
```